# coalesce не работает

Tags: sql, postgresql

Пытаюсь обновить пользователя:

```js
const queryForUpdatePerson = `
                    UPDATE person
                    SET user_name=COALESCE($1, person.user_name),
                    full_name=COALESCE($2, person.full_name),
                    email=COALESCE($3, person.email),
                    password=COALESCE($4, person.password),
                    avatar=COALESCE($5, person.avatar),
                    description=COALESCE($6, person.description)
                    WHERE id = $7 RETURNING *
                `;
                const updatePerson = db.query(queryForUpdatePerson, [userName, fullName, email, password, avatar, description, id]);
```

Данные приходят такие:

```js
{
  id: -1,
  user_name: 'alexey',
  full_name: null,
  email: null,
  avatar: null,
  description: null,
  password: null,
  oldPassword: null,
  newPassword: null,
  roles: [ '' ]
}
```

По этим данным должно измениться только имя, а все остальное остаться старым, но ничего не изменяется и остается старым

Comment: А у тебя точно есть запись с `person.id = -1`?

Comment: нет, но я это и не использую. id беру из req.params

Comment: А как Вы проверяете работоспособность ничего не выполняющего запроса? Если у Вас нет записи с id = -1, то как Вы определили что "не работает coalesce"? Ведь если запрос ничего не обновил он ничего и не вернет в `returning`

Comment: id = -1 я не использую. id забираю из req.params, там он 1, пользователь находится